# jquery set value of all inputs inside a certain td

Tags: jquery

I have a table...

```
        <table id="tblTransactions" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-md-1">Date</th>
              <th class="col-md-4">Description</th>
              <th class="col-md-2">Debit</th>
              <th class="col-md-2">Credit</th>
              <th class="col-md-3">Category</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${transactions}" var="element"> 
              <tr>
                <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${element.tranDate}"/></td>
                <td class="colTranDesc">${element.tranDescription}</td>
                <td>${element.debit}</td>
                <td>${element.credit}</td>
                <td class="colCategory"><input type="text" class="eetag" name="tag"></td>
              </tr>
            </c:forEach>              
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

After the page loads I want to set the value for each input for every td with the class "colCategory".

I would like the selector to look something like this but am having troubles with the syntax...

```
$("#tblTransactions > tbody  > tr > td > input.colCategory").each(function(){
    var elt = $(this).val("Phone");
});
```

Could someone help me with this syntax please. Or if there is a simpler way of doing it I'm open to suggestions.

thx

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. why you are traversing the `DOM`  form `table`.
2. why you are looking onto `colCategory` class why don't you use `class of input tag` that is `eetag.`
3. Are you placed this code into `$(document).ready()` function.

Any way Try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //by using td class
      $(".colCategory").each(function(){
            $(this).find('input').val("Phone");
      })
})
```

OR simple way is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //by using input class
      $(".eetag").each(function(){
            $(this).val("Phone");
       })
})
```

Comment: yes you are correct. The simple way you have mentioned is more correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your `td` has class `colCategory` but in selector you are specifying `input.colCategory`. So it is searching for all `input's` that has class `colCategory`

You should say like bellow

```
$("#tblTransactions > tbody  > tr > td.colCategory > input").each(function(){
    var elt = $(this).val("Phone");
});
```

So here it will search `inputs` in `td's` which have class `colCategory`.

Comment: Also there is no need for the `.each()`. You can call `.val()` directly on the set.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli but that is when there is only one element is there.

Comment: nope.. as with most jquery setting methods, `.val()` applies to all elements of the jquery set. (*when reading a value, though, it will only return the first matched*) see demo at http://jsfiddle.net/mczpht9s/